# Global classes with Meteor >0.6.0 and CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

Since the release of Meteor 0.6.0 and the addition of [file-level JavaScript variable scoping](http://meteor.com/blog/2013/04/04/meteor-060-brand-new-distribution-system-app-packages-npm-integration), I'm facing an issue using CoffeeScript classes, each of them being defined in its own respective file.

foo.coffee:

```
class Foo
  ...
```

subfoo.coffee:

```
class Subfoo extends Foo
  ...
```

As expected, and because of the changes introduced in Meteor 0.6.0, I'm getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: Foo is not defined

Here's my question: how should one handle class definitions across files with CoffeeScript and Meteor >0.6.0? Ideally: is there a convenient way *not* to modify too much the way classes are defined in order to make sure these definitions (and core parts of my application) are not Meteor-dependent?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As noted in the CoffeeScript section of the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#coffeescript):

> Global variables can be set in CoffeeScript by using this (or
>   CoffeeScript's @ shorthand)

As it turns out, CoffeeScript classes can be defined like:

```
class @Foo
```

which compiles to:

```
this.Foo = (function() {
  function Foo() {}
  return Foo;
})();
```

Assuming that `foo.coffee` is loaded before `subfoo.coffee` you can then do:

```
class @Subfoo extends Foo
```

Assuming, of course, that `Subfoo` needs be be assigned to the global scope. It's also worth mentioning that you'll need to expose your collections in a similar way. For example:

```
@Players = new Meteor.Collection 'players'
```

Comment: When trying to implement your solution, I just realized that 'foo.coffee' was nested in the wrong place in my directory structure and thus 'Foo' class was invisible in 'subfoo.coffee' because of Meteor's load order rules. After moving 'foo.coffee' to a more appropriate directory, using 'class @ Foo' and 'class @ Subfoo extends Foo' works [note: spaces inserted in this comment after '@' to avoid mentions]. However, I'm still a bit concerned about having to edit all my application classes and prefix class names with '@' everywhere - but I'll live with that for now! Thanks

Comment: Ah that's interesting. I didn't know that was valid CoffeeScript. Yet another tidbit not specified in the docs...

Comment: I didn't know either this was valid CoffeeScript until I played around with js2coffee.org. I edited the question accordingly and removed my own (erroneous and misleading) proposal. I suggest editing your answer to add the 'class @Foo extends Subfoo' solution as well!

Comment: Yeah I just rewrote the whole answer. Hopefully other people can quickly find the information they need now.

Comment: Note that this will be improve soon with the work on the `linker` branch

Comment: Note that when you setup `@Players`, you should still refer to it as Players everywhere else. (Because `@Players` doesn't work deep within other functions, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Also note that classes such as "Foo" are themselves a value, that you can assign to variables or put into a namespace yourself.

Using `class @Foo` is a great shortcut when you want to put that value directly into the global namespace.

But if you want to, you can also leave variables local and then add them to the global namespace yourself:

```
class Foo
  ...

Players = new Meteor.Collection 'players'

doThat = -> ...

_.extend(this, {Foo, Players, doThat})
```

Or if you'd prefer, you can have your "foo" module define just one global object `foo` that contains the exported values:

```
@foo = {Foo, Players, doThat}
```

Now modules that use the "foo" module can reference the values through the global variable `foo`:

```
class Subfoo extends foo.Foo
  ...
```

Or, if you'd rather be able to type just `Foo` even when exporting only `foo`, you can unwrap `foo` at the top:

```
{Foo, Players, doThat} = foo

class Subfoo extends Foo
  ...
```