# In meteor 0.6.4.1/coffeescript, how does variable visibility work?

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I'm new to meteor and coffeescript.  I'm using the file layout suggested in the Unofficial Meteor FAQ.  In file collections/C.coffee, I have

```
C = new Meteor.Collection 'C'
console.log "C: #{C}"
```

In file server/main.coffee, I have

```
C.insert {test: 'test'}
```

When I start meteor, I see on the console:

```
C: [object Object]
ReferenceError: C is not defined
    at app/server/main.coffee.js:5:1
    at /home/xxx/yyy/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:298:12
```

How do I make C available in files outside of collections/C.coffee?

Update: Adding @ to C fixes the problem at the top level.  However it still fails with:

```
   Meteor.methods
        test: (statement) ->
             @C.insert {test: 'test'}
```

It fails with an error  `TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831144/global-classes-with-meteor-0-6-0-and-coffeescript You have to use @ in front of C

Comment: Thanks, Subrubio.  Any suggestions on my updated example?

Comment: You only need to use @/this when you set the global variable.

Comment: Got it.  That fixes the problems I having.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make C visible outside the file it was defined in use `@`, which compiles to `this.` or `window.` in js, which gives it the same effect as a global scope:

```
@C = new Meteor.Collection 'C'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that once and it failed, so I thought it was wrong. It works fine now at the top level. But I'm also trying to use C inside of a Meteor.methods call.  Is there an equivelant to window. on the server side?

Comment: On the server side I think it would do `this.` instead since there isn't a window on the server

Comment: Please see my updated example.  @ inside of test() points to something different.

Comment: I think you only use `@` when declaring it, but use it normally when getting its value. In the context of the method I think `@` becomes the `this` for that method's context

Comment: On the server side `@` is equal to `global` at the top-level context. But you needn't use `global.C` to access it; you can just do `C`.