# Errors local collection: coffeescript vs javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

In my project i'm using coffeescript.
But today, something I can not understand....

In `/client/helpers/errors.coffee` I write:

```
  Errors = new Meteor.Collection(null)
```

and nothing works! In Chrome console:

```
  Exception from Deps recompute: ReferenceError: Errors is not defined
```

But when I remove `/client/helpers/errors.coffee` and add `/client/helpers/errors.js` with

```
  Errors = new Meteor.Collection(null);
```

everything works! How is this possible?

```
$ mrt list --using
...
coffeescript
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ meteor --version
Release 0.7.0.1
```

Comment: Maybe cofee script package affect it. U can try _Errors = new Meteor.Client(null) :)

Comment: The same result: `Exception from Deps recompute: ReferenceError: _Errors is not defined`. Error occurs in `Template.errors.helpers`

Comment: In coffeescript you need to deal with variable scoping like in JS (removing the `var` keyword), use `@_Errors` instead

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150532/in-meteor-0-6-4-1-coffeescript-how-does-variable-visibility-work

Comment: Thanx, Akshat! Can you make as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Errors = new Meteor.Collection(null)` instead