# Meteor Collection is not accessible in client side when using CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

If i use simple .js file and create a collection in it

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts");
if(Meteor.isClient){
...
...
}
```

i could access the "posts" collection in browser i.e

```
> Posts.find().count();
  4
```

but if i use CoffeScript instead of JavaScript

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection "posts"
if Meteor.isClient
 ...
 ...
```

i couldn't access and it throws an error

```
> Posts.find().count();
  ReferenceError: Posts is not defined
```

because CoffeeScript variables are file-scoped by default..How can i overcome this issue..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global classes with Meteor >0.6.0 and CoffeeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831144/global-classes-with-meteor-0-6-0-and-coffeescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because CoffeeScript variables are file-scoped by default..How can i
>   overcome this issue..?

Prefix it with `@`, which will compile to `this.` in JavaScript, so it will be added to the `window` object, which is the global scope on the client side in JavaScript.

`@Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts");`

Comment: Yes it solves my problem but is that a correct way of doing it?
`this.Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts");` doesn't seems correct.

Comment: @Rajanand02 That's the way to go. I guess you could write `window.Posts = ...` on the client, but then your code would break on the server, since the `window` object doesn't exists there (the server has the `global` object instead).