# Meteor Basic App: ReferenceError: Entries is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hi I am doing a basic tutorial of meteor.  I am attempting to insert a name directly into the database from the javascript console of a chrome web browser.  As I do this, I get the following error (relevant code is below):

Error code within the javascript console in web browser

```
Entries.insert({name: 'Tommy'})
ReferenceError: Entries is not defined
```

raffler.coffee

```
Entries = new Meteor.Collection("entries")

if Meteor.isClient
  Template.raffle.entries = -> Entries.find()
```

raffler.html
    
      Raffler

```
<body>
  <div id="container">{{> raffle}}</div>
</body>

<template name="raffle">
  <h1>Raffler</h1>

  <ul id="entries">
    {{#each entries}}
      {{name}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: You probably mean `Entries.insert`, no? And `raffler.coffee` is on both the server and the client? where is it in your project tree?

Comment: Yes I meant insert, same error.  I edited it.  Here is the project tree: raffler folder (arrow down) .meteor (arrow down) raffler.coffee; raffler.css; raffler.html; local folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Entries` needs to be defined in the global scope on both the server and the client. You can do that in CoffeeScript with:

```coffee
@Entries = new Meteor.Collection 'entries'
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831144/global-classes-with-meteor-0-6-0-and-coffeescript).